# Camera not working in Android 12 using Scan plugin

Tags: flutter, camera, scanning, android-12, flutter-android

In my flutter app, I am using the [scan](https://pub.dev/packages/scan) plugin for barcode scanning and facing the below issue.

I have given permission according to the plugin which they provided but the Camera is not open in android 12 devices and it shows me a white screen after giving permission.

Is there any solution or is there any permission which I missed to add?[Image shows white screen instead of the camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2IPL.jpg)

Comment: are you using this plugin flutter_barcode_scanner 2.0.0 , please mention flutter version to

Comment: no i am using scan plugin here is the plugin link: https://pub.dev/packages/scan .I am using flutter 2.5.1